# How can I write jpa repository method for m:m relationship?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a m:m relationship between `EntityOne` and `EntityTwo`

```
public class EntityTwo{
     private String name;
     @ManyToMany //config here
     private List<EntityOne> entities;
}

public class EntityOne{
     private String description;
     @ManyToMany //config here
     private List<EntityTwo> entities;
}
```

How can I create a method for `EntityOne` repository without using the `@Query` annotation for fetching all the `EntityOne` rows based on `EntityTwo`'s name ? I've tried something like :

`List<EntityOne> findAllByEntityTwoName(String name)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Regarding the findBy pattern you have to specify the attribute's name, not the type. `findAllByEntities(String name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Spring data query methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods) to achieve your task. Basically, spring data generates a query based on some rules you define your method with.

```
@Repository
public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityOne, UUID> {

    List<EntityOne> findAllByEntities_Name(String name);
}
```

In the `findAllByEntities_Name()` method, you are using query method along with [Property Expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions) to create a search by name property in entites(`EntityTwo`) field from `EntityOne`

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome. Happy development!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you need to query `EntityOne` based on the field `name` in `EntityTwo`.

You can create a method like this: `findAllBy` + Name of `EntityTwo` defined in `EntityOne` + `EntityTwo` attribute names, based on which you need to filter

So in you case it would be

```java
List<EntityOne> findAllByEntitiesName(String name);
```